# Displaying a water flow system on Bing Maps in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

How could I best represent pipes in a water system on Bing Maps?

I already have location data for various equipment such as valves that I can use as points on a map. I was hoping to just use regular lines to connect these points on the map. However, I need to dynamically change pipes (i.e. line drawn when there is water flow, line erased when no water flow). I'm planning to use C# and WPF.

Comment: Is this a question on design or implementation in WPF? It sounds like you have absolutely no idea what you are going to be doing and you want SO to design and implement your project.

Comment: It's a design issue I'm having. At this point I'm trying to decide if I'll use Bing maps or a simple bitmap with a line overlay to represent the pipe system. I'd prefer Bing maps because I do have location data associated with equipment, but I have no idea how or where to get started with the implementation (never used bing maps api before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Google "Bing Maps WPF Control" then the first result is the Microsoft MSDN page for it which contains all the information you need including sample code for adding both static and dynamic lines and shapes to a map.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. I was just getting lost searching for the wrong things, trying to wade through too much useless information.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I saw your generic question about this got deleted yesterday...a bit harsh IMO. For what it's worth WPF is exactly the right technology for the project you're developing, but don't forget there are other mapping technologies out there that will work equally well including Google maps and OpenStreetMap (which doesn't have satellite imagery but is free). If you do decide to use a different tech then you'd typically use a Canvas control with the background set to your map and templating used to render your items with the appropriate visual representation.